# How can I save an object in the file?

Tags: java, file

How can I save an object in the file?  I have an Object obj,how can I save all its information such as:

```
m.getName();
m.getFamily()
```

and the others in the file???

Answer (score 5):

Using an ObjectOutputStream you can write the object directly into the file.

```
 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("filename.dat")));
 out.writeObject(obj);
 out.close();
```

This writes the Object obj out to the file. It can be read back in use an ObjectInputStream().

Comment: This technique can also be used to send arbitrary objects over a socket stream.

Answer (score 2):

since xml is more readable and transferable, i use [Simple Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/), or as mentioned you could do simple serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You may be after [serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

Answer (score 1):

My workplace uses [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), if `ObjectOutputStream` doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to store the object and retrieve it back as a whole , better go with serialization.

In case, you want a readable file with the contents of the object , use file-IO API to write the contents to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer, but Apache [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has [SerializationUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html)

```
SerializationUtils.serialize(Serializable obj, OutputStream outputStream).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) to write objects to xml files.